# What am I supposed to do if pulled over by a police officer in the US and I can't roll down my car's windows?

Tags: usa, driving

What am I supposed to do if pulled over by a police officer in the US and for some reason I can't roll down my car's windows?

On pretty much all websites I have seen so far they indicate one must not open the door, e.g. https://trafficschoolonline.com/blog/things-to-do-stopped-by-police:

> Don't make a move to open the door or do anything else unless you're told to.

---

Example of reason why I can't roll down my car's windows:

[image]

Comment: Will this be all your windows at the same time?

Comment: @Willeke yes~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Pull off the sticker and hold it against the window?

Comment: The downvoter should justify why they downvoted this justfied question. Such a sticker is truly strange since it does not state when the 48 hours start, thus no one would know when it ends.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I added some tint on the windows and the instructions say I shouldn't roll down the windows within 48 hours after the tinting was done.

Comment: Oh-je, then you yourself are to blame (you have my sympathy, for no one likes to omit that). I would say that the sticker on a cardboard (with a date and time) would be a better solution (one of those that one thinks of after it is to late).

Comment: "Don't open the door **unless you are told to**" - if you mime that you can't open the window, you or the officer can open the door.

Comment: A single blown fuse could prevent all windows from opening at the same time.  I've borrowed a work car with a fault that meant you couldn't always shut them again after opening (and a big sign saying don't open them, probably visible from outside).  Of course we ignored the sign, especially when encountering one of the few (and heavily) armed police we have here, guarding a defence- or nuclear-related site

Comment: That this is even a question confirms how messed up the US Police system is and how scared people are that they will be shot

Answer (score 3):

The best thing is to indicate with your hands that the window doesn't work, you should do this by keeping your hands visible at all times so the officer can ensure their safety. The officer has probably pulled over people before whose windows don't work and I'm sure they'll understand.

As *Willeke* suggested this will be unlikely that all the windows cannot be opened, if this is the case you can laminate a sign saying something like:

> Window doesn't work please use passenger window

Alternatively, maybe the officer can pop the door while holding it, just enough that you can talk through the crack.